# Nested getRecords in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a community Lightning Web Component that we are creating and we need to the the accountId and then from there get the Account Name and other fields based on the accountId

So we have functionality of getting the AccountId from the user record. Code below:

```
    @wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '0053i000001YDcX',
    fields: [NAME_FIELD, EMAIL_FIELD],
    optionalFields: [ACCOUNT_ID]
}) wireuser({
    error,
    data
}) {
    if (error) {
       this.error = error ; 
    } else if (data) {
        this.email = data.fields.Email.value;
        this.name = data.fields.Name.value;
        this.accountId = data.fields.AccountId.value;
    }
}
```

But what I don't know how do we do a nested lookup to get the Account information because when I do a separate getRecords the `this.accountId` is not filled in yet so I get an error when using that as the `recordId`

What i thought to do

```
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: this.accountId,
    fields: [ACCOUNT_NAME]
}) wireaccount({
    error,
    data
}) {
    if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    } else if (data) {
        this.accountName = data.fields.AccountName.value;
    }
}
```

Any help in any directions will be helpful

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Wired service will not run when any of the properties are `undefined` and will automatically re-fetch the data when dependent dynamic properties changes. So, you have to make `this.accountId` into dynamic parameter by changing it to `$accountId`.

```
accountId; // this should be undefined. Do not assign value. When it gets the value from user-record, below wire is invoked

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$accountId',
    fields: [ACCOUNT_NAME]
}) wireaccount({
    error,
    data
}) { --- logic ---  }
```

This will not be invoked until `accountId` is assigned a value.

---

**Added based on comments:**

I did not use `@api` for accountId/recordId (by calling recordId) because according to question, this component is not used directly in target record context as mentioned in question:

> So we have functionality of getting the AccountId from the user record

Comment: It is worth pointing out that if you are using the component in a lightning record page and you want to use it in both community and standard context then it is best to call the "accountId" field "recordId" and make sure it is annotated (at)api. Then all you do is drop it into the page and it will pick up the page's record's ID automatically. With community use you also need to set up a target config property called recordId that is initialized as $recordId.

Comment: Thanks Phil, actually question says "So we have functionality of getting the AccountId from the user record", so didnt suggest that. Added in answer

Comment: Yeah, but I read the "community LWS component" bit and wondering what the context is. Thus my comment. A "just in case" point.